# Build Docker Images, Error: standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Tags: portia

I am building a Docker Image for portia, but when i am follow all steps below, when i run the docker run, it comes out the error:

> standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or
>   directory"

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcxpA.png)

The steps I am following.

**Step 1**

```
mkdir portia

cd portia

git clone github.com/scrapinghub/portia.git

cd portia

git checkout update_installation

mkdir ~/data

cd portiaui

npm install && bower install

cd node_modules/ember-cli && npm install && cd ../../ && ember build

cd ..

docker build -t portia:v1 .

docker run -i -t --rm -p 9001:9001 -v ~/data:/app/data/projects ~/portia
/portia/portiaui/dist:/app/portiaui/dist portia:v1
```

Point a browser to localhost:9001

**From github.com/scrapinghub/portia/issues/699 that i am following**

**Step 2**

```
mkdir ~/data

git clone git@github.com:scrapinghub/portia.git

cd portia/portiaui

npm install && bower install

cd node_modules/ember-cli && npm install && cd ../../

ember build

cd ..
```

then

```
docker build . -t portia
```

Thank You